Save Flutter Web Apps to Phone Home Screen
We can save any website to our home screen and open it like a mobile app. It works with any website I assume. I have a weird situation. I have a Flutter Web app to save to my phone's home screen too. The problem is it's not getting the URL from my Flutter App.
Eg.
If I save this website: 'https://x.com/someUserID'
It will saved as it is. But somehow if I save my Flutter App which has a URL something like this: 'https://example.com/customPath/someID'
It's get saved as 'https://example.com/'
It's always cutting the URL and just saving the base URL instead. Is there any workaround for that? I want to save the exact URL which is working that way for every other website.
I've tried to use both go_router package and named routes but It's not working as expected either way.
Any idea would be helpful. Thank you

I guess, By using flutter we create web apps not website. So, when we save the webapp on home screen it'll save with the home url or that webapp.

First, make sure your Flutter Web app is configured as a Progressive Web App (PWA). This involves having a manifest.json file and a service worker, are you doing that @Emre? Also are you using deep links inside the project?

Yes, I'm sure that my app is configured as PWA. But I'm not using any deep links, only using go_router.

This may be related to the type of phone, even if it isn't a PWA on a iPhone it will save from the current URL.

I will suggest you to file an issue on https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues

Try using the path url strategy. https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/navigation/url-strategies

Using the URL path strategy also had no effect
